# How to check if user has liked the facebook application?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Previously, I was checking if user has liked the facebook app or not using the following code:

```
    $fql= "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = '$appid' and uid='".$me['id']."'";
    $param=array(
        'method'    => 'fql.query',
        'query'     => $fql,
        'access_token' => $access_token
    );
    $fqlResult1   =   $facebook->api($param);
    $hasliked = count($fqlResult1);
```

But now this code doesn't work anymore. Is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook has blocked the feature that we can check whether facebook apps are blocked or not from about 6,8 months.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
$facebook->api("/$user/likes");
```

It provides list of likes for the user. If you application is in the list then its liked by the user else not.
Did you mean something like that.

Comment: Thanks sudhir for your response. This gives the name of the application. But it doesn't give the unique id from which the application can  be identified. For eg. if there are apps with same name then it is very difficult to distinguish. Is there any alternative for this?

Answer (score 0):

you can check by specifying your page id while giving api call like this

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/Likes/" + pageId/appId + "?access_token=" + oAuthToken
```

if response contains data it means your page/app is liked otherwise not.